# How to change NavigationBarColor while app running

Tags: ios, swift

I use this to set NavigationBarColor before it run:

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Color.NavigationBackground
```

But in the program,I want to change the NavigationBarColor, So I use this again

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Color.Black
```

But nothing happen, It still white(Color.Background)
Color is a struct that I defined.
How to change the color correctly?
I want to achieve like this:[Trying to reload view controller to update the current theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697172/trying-to-reload-view-controller-to-update-the-current-theme)

Comment: Do you want to change navigation bar color or table view background????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing navigation bar color in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687238/changing-navigation-bar-color-in-swift)

Comment: UITableView,I call it NavigationBar. I want to achieve some kind like this,but it is not working.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697172/trying-to-reload-view-controller-to-update-the-current-theme

Comment: only navigation color or whole app color(that would be themes)

Comment: can you edit your question and briefly expalin what do you want to achieve

Comment: I found the solution, sorry I just paste the code wrong.

Comment: If you have answered your own question please mention your answer below and also if one of the below answers is correct please mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want each screen to have different color add below line with color of your choice in view will appear and it will change color for each screen.

Swift 4.2:

```
//To change Navigation Bar Background Color
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue
//To change Back button title & icon color
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
//To change Navigation Bar Title Color
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

add it in view will appear and then you can see it changing.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .orange
}
```

Comment: I use this and nothing happen, the color stay the same. How to reload it?

Comment: on which action do you want to change color?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the color of navigation bar color

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the appearance API, and barTintColor color.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewController's` `viewWillAppear(_:)` simply set `navigationBar's` `barTintColor` as your required `color`, i.e.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to set `UINavigationBar` color initially in your `Appdelegate`’s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = Color.Background
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Color.Background
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
```

And when you want to change color of `UINavigationBar` within app, just use these lines of code. Let’s say change color is your button action.

```
    @IBAction func changeThemeColor(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = Color.Black
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Color.Black
    }
```